# How to read RREQ message header from MAC layer

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am considering a multihop sensor network scenario with AODV routing protocol and X-MAC protocol. I want to read the *message type* field of RREQ message from MAC layer. Would anyone please suggest me the code for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link layer protocols (like X-MAC) should NOT depend on any protocol that is above them. Just like an ethernet device driver should not contain any code dealing with TCP window size. You should consider to have a software architecture which reflects how services are working in real life.

Comment: Hi Rudi, X-MAC treats RREQ messages as data packet, so follows the same cycle of sending data packet. Is there any way, so X-MAC will not treat RREQ messages as data packet? Thank you.

Comment: No, data coming from an upper layer is opaque to the mac layer. It's just data, that's all. If you want to do something spacial with a packet, you can implement that behavior in the X-MAC code, but that code must be triggered in response to some meta data attached to the packet, instead of the content of the packet itself. RequestTags are used for cross layer communication in INET for these use-cases.

Comment: Example: If you want to transmit all RREQ packets with maximal power on the wireless interface, then you must attach a SignalPowerReq tag (metadata) to the packet in the AODV codebase (where you know all the info what is inside the RREQ). The Radio at the physical layer will understand that SignalPowerReq and act accordingly. In this architecture, the radio does NOT know what is inside the packet. It just knows how to handle the SignalPowerReq. i.e. how to transmit packets with different power.

Comment: Cross protocol communication is important concept to implement this: https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/developers-guide/ch-packets.html#packet-tagging